# how to redirect after delete obj?

Tags: django

i want to redirect to that URL : user/str:username after delete task so I set success_url='user-tasks' but after delete task error (Page not found (404) ) appear . so is there any other way to use success_url ?

```
#-----------------------views.py-----------------------

    class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
        model=tasks
        success_url='user-tasks' # <====  does not work 
        def test_func(self):
            task=self.get_object()
            if self.request.user == task.user:
                return True
            return False

#-----------------------------------------------------

#----------------------urls.py-------------------------------------------------------

    from django.urls import path 
    from . import views
    from . views import TaskListView,TaskCreateView,TaskUpadteView,UserTaskListView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.TaskListView.as_view(),name='home-page'),
        path('task/new/', views.TaskCreateView.as_view(),name='create-task'),
        path('task/<int:pk>/update/', views.TaskUpadteView.as_view(),name='update-task'), 
        path('task/<int:pk>/delete/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete-task'), 
        path('user/<str:username>', views.UserTaskListView.as_view(),name='user-tasks')  
    
    ]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZWB4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can make use of `get_success_url()` :

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model=tasks
    
    def get_success_url(self):         
        return reverse_lazy('user-tasks', kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
```